# System.getProperty("some stuff")

Tags: java

In a very huge code base I found the following code snippet System.getProperty("some stuff"). I tried to look the property in some of the .properties files though i couldn't find it. Do you guys have any ideas where to look the property anywhere else in the code file system?

Comment: Properties can also be defined on the command-line or whatever that was used to start the JVM.

Comment: Depends on what `"some stuff"` is. If it is, e.g. `"user.home"`, that is set from an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into "System.setProperty" in your work space:

```
  // Modifying a system property
  System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir","c:\\var\\tmp");
  // Adding my own properties
  System.setProperty("program.name","Property Test");
  System.setProperty("program.version","3.01");
```